# Hide products from "Latest products" module in Opencart

Tags: css, opencart2.3

I have a problem and don't know how to solve it. My website is based on **Opencart** (v2) with enabled "Latest products" module on the main page.

[image: 1]

As you see in the above picture,  I need to hide products (red background) from "Latest products" where *category = 9*. What is the easiest way to do this and what files need to be modified? I think about **CSS** and `display: none;`

Comment: you can add and remove your required categories from the module by going to extensions/extensions/modules.

Comment: Do you wants to remvoe all products from category 9 or wants just these two specific products ?